# How to add Text to Speech to Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for **System.speech** to work in unity? Is there any way how to include this DLL in unity and MonoDevelop?

Because I'm trying to make a sound text to speech without spend the money from asset store. If **System.Speech** Library DLL could handle this why not. Just how to make it work with unity 5.3.5 ?

Also I have already try **speechLib.dll**. It is work while in editor but when Build to APK it is error and can't build.

Comment: System.Speech is Microsoft .net and Unity runs on mono. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633568/system-speech-in-mono-on-linux

Comment: Hi @SebastianL I have try looking at Mono Project->Edit References-> packages and i can see there is a System.Speech at there. It is at mono, why i can't use it even system.speech is microsoft.net ? Is there any speech DLL version for unity to work with ?

Comment: no there isn't if you want it to work on android/iOS, for this you need a third party lib

Comment: I have bought Android Speech TTS plugin at asset store unity. Hope it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dlls files don't work on Android or iOS unless it is an unmanaged dll file without Windows specified API. If it is a Windows API or a managed dll then it won't work on Android or iOS.

You have two options: Buy a plugin or make your own. If you are only targeting Android and iOS then go for [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/22315) *Easy TTS* which cost $5.

If you want to make one yourself then the process is very similar to my Speech to Text [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611728/how-to-add-speech-recognition-to-unity-project/39613264#39613264). The only difference are the classes used. Making one your self is easy. The only downside is that it is time consuming to make one for each platform.

**Android**:

[TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) class.

**iOS**:

[AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer) class

**MacOS**:

[NSSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer) class

**Windows**:

[ISpVoice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125164(v=vs.85).aspx) class

There are tons of examples of how to use these on the internet. You have to make plugin for the Android class using Java, Objective-C for the iOS and MacOs classes. C++ for the Windows class.

For putting them together, you should use Unity's directive to do that.

```
class TextToSpeech
{
  #if UNITY_ANDROID  
    Use TextToSpeech class
  #endif

  #if UNITY_IOS
    Use AVSpeechSynthesizer class
  #endif

  #if UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_EDITOR_OSX
    Use NSSpeechSynthesizer class
  #endif

  #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR_WIN
    Use ISpVoice class
  #endif 
}
```

Comment: Seem Easy TTS is not good enough. Because it need a setting in android phone before it work. Player will not do any settting in phone but just play.

Comment: @DennisLiu The ratings is really good. What do you have to set in Android?

Comment: It is need to set TTS Engine setting in mobile android. Text-to-speech option and choose Google Text-to-speech Engine. Look at this : https://d2ujflorbtfzji.cloudfront.net/package-screenshot/1baa029f-1b6d-4479-afb2-62c54526abcf_scaled.jpg

Comment: Not really. That's optional. Some Android devices comes with more than 1 Speech Engine. Google and Samsung engines. That screenshot is only showing you how to switch to another engine..

Comment: Ouch... I must have misunderstood that way. It must be wrong to choose Android Speech TTS with cost $9.99 and this also work for only android. :( Thanks @Programmer it is look like i must change the speech plugin when launching the IOS game.

Comment: @DennisLiu Lol I was gonna say that. You can ask for a refund. I noticed that the other on supports iOS too. That's why I recommended it.  Glad I was able to help. I changed the title to so that it can be found and will help others in the future

Comment: Glad to hear that. The title is more suitable now for the answer.

Comment: Seem like "Easy TTS" is not updated anymore. Last package has been submitted using Unity 5.3.5. Maybe ["RT-Voice PRO"](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/audio/rt-voice-pro-41068) could be a better solution becouse have full platforms compatibility and it is updated to unity 2019.4.0